# Puppet language - function each with var return

Tags: return, each, puppet

I have a question with the function `each`. I have this code (http://pastebin.com/tZzq0agQ):

```
$a.each |$hash| {   
    $hash.each |$key, $value| {
        notice "key ${key}, value ${value}"
        notify {'test1':
            message => $value,
        }
    }    
}
notify {'test2':
    message => $value,
}
```

And of course `test2` does not work because I don't return the `$value`. Can someone tell me how to return it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental issue with your question. It is not well defined what `$value` you expect to be "returned".

```
$a = [ { foo => bar, baz => qux }, { a = b, c => d } ]
```

Then the inner loop takes the values

- bar
- qux
- b
- d

It is therefor unclear what value you would want to have returned.